# Randomly select subset from vector in order (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector, subset

I want to select a random subset of a vector, much like `datasample(data,k)`, but I want them in order.

I have an ODE which has `[t,y]` as output and it's the `y` that I want a subset of. I cannot just do a `sort` because `y` is not linear and so I somehow have to sort it with respect to `t`.

Any ideas how I can to this?

Comment: When you say "linear" do you mean "monotonic"?

Comment: Yep! There are a couple of valleys and peaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to **sample the elements maintaining their original order**. You can do it this way:

1. randomly sample the indices rather than the values;
2. sort the sampled indices;
3. use them to access the selected values;

that is:

```
result = data(sort(randsample(numel(data), k)));
```

The above uses the [`randsample`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) function from the Statistics Toolbox. Alternatively, in recent Matlab versions you can use the two-input form of [`randperm`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
result = data(sort(randperm(numel(data), k)));
```

For example, given

```
data = [61 52 43 34 25 16];
k = 4;
```

a possible result is

```
result =
    61    43    34    25
```

Comment: You might want to mention that `randsample` requires the **Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox**.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks! Added

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using a combination of [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) and [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
function q40673112
% Create a vector:
v = round(sin(0:0.6:6),3); disp(['v = ' mat2str(v)]);
% Set the size of sample we want:
N = 5;                
% Create the random indices:
inds = intersect(1:numel(v), randperm(numel(v),N)); disp(['inds = ' mat2str(inds)]);
% Sample from the vector:
v_samp = v(inds); disp(['v_samp = ' mat2str(v_samp)]);
```

Example output:

```
%    1    2    3     4     5     6      7      8      9      10     11
v = [0 0.565 0.932 0.974 0.675 0.141 -0.443 -0.872 -0.996 -0.773 -0.279]
inds = [4 6 9 10 11]
v_samp = [0.974 0.141 -0.996 -0.773 -0.279]
```